# html5 canvas script looping font

Tags: loops, canvas

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id=cvs width=400px height=400px />
</body>

<script>
var text = document.getElementById('cvs').getContext('2d');
var x = 30;
for(var j=0, k='a'; j<3; j++,k++;)
{

text.fillStyle='#000';
text.font="30px Arial";
text.fillText(k,x,30);
x=x+60;
}
</script>
</html>
```

the k values contains font..
then i try to print the k values 3times, but it shown "a, NaN, NaN"
please help me to get the loop of font.. thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1):

There is no `char`-Type in JavaScript. Use `.charCodeAt(0)` at the `String`-Object `"a"` to get the char code and use `String.fromCharCode(...)` to convert the char code back to a `String`.

Besides: HTML-Arguments have to be quoted and `width` and `height` take no units. Units are css only!
Besides (2): There is an additional `;` in your `for`.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas id="cvs" width="400" height="400" />
  </body>
  <script>
  var text = document.getElementById('cvs').getContext('2d');
  var x = 30;
  for (var j=0, k="a".charCodeAt(0); j<3; j++,k++)
  {
    text.fillStyle='#000';
    text.font="30px Arial";
    text.fillText(String.fromCharCode(k),x,30);
    x=x+60;
  }
  </script>
</html>
```